# How to send multiple Emails using AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-rds, amazon-ses

i have a mobile application and my data base is in a RDS instance of data base in AWS, i use the AWS SES to send account confirmation Emails to every new user who register in my application. Now i need to send an E-mail to all the 230 users registered in my data base, i need a little help in how to do this, i'm reading the documentation but i'm pretty lost. Is there a way to do this for the AWS console or an software ? I'm not the one who set this up. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post what you've tried and how it has failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. You can call the `SendBulkTemplatedEmail` SES API endpoint. You can read more and see examples that accomplish exactly what you want to do [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/introducing-email-templates-and-bulk-sending/).

Bear in mind you can only send up to 50 emails at a time